# I am researching on solving classification problems on e-commerce platforms. what metaheuristic approach will be most suitable

Tags: classification, e-commerce

I am on research about evaluating customer satisfaction and dissatisfaction on 5 major e-commerce platforms. I thought of using a metaheuristic approach for the analysis and a Python script to mine data from these platforms in solving this but I am not making a head-through. Previous research made use of questionnaires to generate data; SPSS, Cohort analysis, Linear regression, CNN, and NPS among others to analyze and classify data. Technology is evolving rapidly and metaheuristics have proved a good approach to solving optimization and real-life problems but they should also be able to solve other problems optimally. Using metaheuristics for classification will give a more robust and detailed overview of the result.

I have studied the metaheuristic approach and learned they have been used in solving mostly optimization and engineering problems. Computational solution have been lagging and not feasible in solving some real-life and classification problems. I was looking into an approach that better depicts and classify large volume of customer data timely and optimally.